# Are all solutions to this coupled PDE constant?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

This is a self-answered question. I posted it here since it wasn't trivial for me. I would be happy to see alternative solutions.

---

Suppose $\theta(x,y),\tilde \theta(x,y)$ are smooth functions on a connected domain, and define
$$
c=\cos(\theta),s=\sin(\theta),\tilde c=\cos(\tilde \theta),\tilde s=\sin(\tilde \theta).
$$
Suppose that the following coupled system of PDE's is satisfied:
$$
(1) \,\,\,\,\partial_x(\tilde sc)=-\partial_y(c\tilde c),
$$
$$
(2) \,\,\,\, \partial_y(\tilde s c)=\partial_x(c\tilde c), \,\,\,\,\,
$$
$$
(3) \,\,\,\,\partial_x(s\tilde c)=\partial_y(s\tilde s),\,\,\,\,\,\,
$$
$$
(4) \,\,\,\,\partial_y(s\tilde c)=-\partial_x(s\tilde s).\,\,\,\,
$$

How to prove that $\theta,\tilde \theta$ are constant functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system $(1)-(2)$ implies that $f=-\tilde sc+i(c\tilde c)=i\cos(\theta)e^{i\tilde \theta}$ is holomorphic, and $(3)-(4)$ imply that $g=s\tilde c+i(s\tilde s)=\sin(\theta)e^{i\tilde \theta}$ is holomorphic.
Thus $(if)^2+g^2=e^{2i\tilde \theta}$ is holomorphic. Since its image lies inside a circle, the open mapping theorem implies that it is constant. Thus $\tilde \theta$ is constant.

Together with the holomorphicity of $f$, we deduce that $\cos(\theta)$ is holomorphic, so $\theta$ is also constant.